# File Upload taking lots of time Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am using codeigniter for my project and the file upload is taking a lot of time in server. When a user uploads images of size above 3 MB, its taking more than 1 minute to upload. Is there any way to speed up file upload process or does it depend upon the net connection being used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a normal scenario, upload speed mainly on the user's connection speed. Most Internet connections are slower uploading than downloading.

You could try out [SWFUpload's Speed Plugin Demo](http://demo.swfupload.org/v250beta3/speeddemo/index.php) to find out whether it's the connection, or whether it's really the server taking a lot of time to process the uploaded data. In the latter case, you would have to provide more information about what your script does.

Comment: When i uploaded an image of size 3.5 MB in the above link , this is what i got....what do you make of it

Files Queued:  0
Files Uploaded:  1
Errors:  0
 
Current Speed:  477.33 Kbps
Average Speed:  467.86 Kbps
Moving Average Speed:  541.08 Kbps
Time Remaining  0 s
Time Elapsed  1 m 9.27 s
Percent Uploaded  100.00 %
Size Uploaded  3.96 MB
Progress Event Count  121

Comment: @Sanjai how long does it take when you upload it to your CI site?

Comment: @Pekka ... I took me around 1 minute to upload the same image.

Comment: @Sanjai so there is no measurable difference, correct? Then it is indeed the user's connection.

Comment: @Pekka....i agree too...but generally speaking, is there any way to improve the performance of file upload. Client insist upon increasing performance...!!!!!

Comment: @Sanjai nope. Except for compressing the data before sending (useless for JPG images though, they are already compressed) and of course getting a faster connection. What I have done in situations like that is set up a local mirror of the site at the client's site, and build an uploading mechanism that mirrors the site daily. A *huge* undertaking, of course.

Comment: @Pekak... now when i uploaded an image of size 1 MB it took me only 7.75 seconds while the same image took 33 sec in my CI application. what could be the problem

Comment: @Sanjai it could be what your application does with the image.

Comment: @Pekka ... i upload the image using CI's upload library and resize the image using the image manipulation library....thats all am doing...not sure what the issue is

Comment: @Sanjai I don't know - it could be that the resizing takes that much time, although it's unlikely. You may have to do some profiling to find out what takes that much time.

Comment: @Sanjai see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/514653/what-are-the-ways-to-find-bottlenecks-in-a-web-application