# MEAN.JS, high latence / ways to find bottlenecks in web-development

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, meanjs

:)

I recently came across [MEAN.JS](http://meanjs.org/). I'm still a beginner in webdevelopment but all worked really fine so far. Up to one thing.

Unfortunately, all requests seem to take a huge amount of time - 300 - 4000(!) ms for a single call (have a look at the screenshot). I'm developing locally on a state of the art computer and wonder where the bottleneck might be. Does anyone have the same issues? Could you give me a hint how to attack this problem?

I've had a look at this and similar posts, but couldn't find a way to tackle it.

[What are the ways to find bottlenecks in a web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514653/what-are-the-ways-to-find-bottlenecks-in-a-web-application)

The framework uses MongoDB, ExpressJS, AngularJS, Node.js. Could you give me a hint how to track down the source of those latencies in a Javascript-based application? (Maybe a tool, plugin or best practice approach in development?) Have you experienced similar issues?

Greetings,
Tea

[image: Console-Screenshot. High latencies.]

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to guess what's wrong as that latency can be originated from many sources, however if we put aside computer and network problems/configurations, and taking into account that you don't have any other processes running that can affect your app performance, the first thing I would check is the express configuration, i.e, the order in which the middleware is loaded. A misplaced middleware can indeed influence the app's performance.

Comment: Thank you very much for that hint. :) I'm still searching and post my findings here.